snap causing stuttering behavior in Ubuntu 22.04
Since the last Ubuntu 22.04 updates (a couple of days ago), I've been experiencing stuttering in my machine (in videos, mouse, typing, etc). It seems that snap is the root cause of this because, every time there's stuttering, I get these messages in the output of journalctl -f
Apr 23 20:41:42 samus systemd[2045]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Apr 23 20:41:42 samus systemd[2045]: Started VTE child process 79461 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 36990.
Apr 23 20:42:28 samus NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1713922948.4143] dhcp6 (enp3s0): state changed new lease, address=fdc4:97b3:fa34:10::56d 2803:9810:608e:f110::56d
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_firefox' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_geckodriver' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_gimp_gimp' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_snap-store' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software-local-file' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snapd-desktop-integration_snapd-desktop-integration' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_spotify_spotify' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_vlc_vlc' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): connected
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): 300.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): connected
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): 300.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_firefox' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_geckodriver' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_gimp_gimp' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_snap-store' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software-local-file' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snapd-desktop-integration_snapd-desktop-integration' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_spotify_spotify' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:32 samus systemd-udevd[79550]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_vlc_vlc' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:43:38 samus NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1713923018.4144] dhcp6 (enp3s0): state changed new lease, address=fdc4:97b3:fa34:10::56d 2803:9810:608e:f110::56d
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_firefox' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_geckodriver' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_gimp_gimp' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_snap-store' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software-local-file' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snapd-desktop-integration_snapd-desktop-integration' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_spotify_spotify' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_vlc_vlc' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): connected
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): 300.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): connected
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG FULL HD (DFP-3): 300.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2160]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_firefox' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_firefox_geckodriver' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_gimp_gimp' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_snap-store' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snap-store_ubuntu-software-local-file' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_snapd-desktop-integration_snapd-desktop-integration' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_spotify_spotify' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 23 20:44:13 samus systemd-udevd[79638]: card0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper snap_vlc_vlc' failed with exit code 1.

Have you experienced this? How can I keep debugging this issue to fix it for good?
Thanks

Do you have any GNOME extensions (other than the default Ubuntu ones) enabled? Are you able to try using a different port and/or cable to connect your monitor? Reasons for suspecting that: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263112 and https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/systemd-is-logging-list-of-nvidia-gpu-interfaces-each-30-seconds-all-the-time/66545

@johnandmegh I have the Desktop Matrix extension. Not sure if these are default ones but they are under /usr/share/gnome-shell/extension: ding@rastersoft.com  ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com  ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.
I don't have a different port but I could try a different cable.

Does the issue persist if you disable the Workspace Matrix (assuming that's the one you mean) extension?

I haven't tried disabling it, however, today when my PC woke up from suspension, I noticed there were two notificatoins from snapd. One related to spotify and one just saying that snap store was updated. I closed both notifications and the problem stopped.  Yesterday I tried restarting the computer and nothing happened. Maybe those notifications were causing the issue? The only thing I know is that the messages disappeared once I got rid of the notifications.

@johnandmegh false alarm. After suspending the PC and coming back again, the issue started happening. So what I know is that it's not persistent and it may stop happening after suspension. I'll keep checking...

@johnandmegh update: one of my monitors is connected to an HDMI port, the other one to a DisplayPort. I saw the messages referred to the DisplayPort and following your suggestion, I changed it to another port. After that, the error is gone. I'll keep monitoring the terminal

My syslog is getting spammed by snap-device-helper failures.  When you say "false alarm" does that mean I have to figure out what is wrong with my NVIDIA drivers or something?  I really don't like having to wade through a bunch of spam messages in syslog when trying to debug actual problems.  Saying "ignore them" is no good. False alarms are not to be ignored.  They are to be eliminated.

@JamesBowery what I meant with false alarm is that I thought the messages disappeared after I closed the notifications but it happened again after coming back from suspension. The problem stopped after I changed the port
